# How to add a vhost entry where you have a docroot path which has a symlink in it

Tags: web, nginx, symlink, bamboo

i am setting up a staging server which has a cicd setup where codes are deployed as per releases. I have a domain which is pointing to a path say: docroot/project/web/abc_com/web/ but this path contains a symlink. 
the docroot/project/web/  points to a symlink:  docroot/builds/releases/current .

Now with every new release i have to restart the nginx so that the domain is pointing to the current release. How do i fix this

ln -sf docroot/builds/releases/current docroot/project/web/

Comment: "with every new release" - do you mean when you change the symlink or when you add content to the symlinked directory?

Comment: yes the symlink changes every release. But the nginx cached the older path.

Comment: Why do you have Nginx caching these static files?

Comment: that is the default behaviour of Nginx it takes the absolute while setting the docroot .  and does not check for symlink changes in between the inner folders

Comment: I didn't see that. When I tested this, changing the value of a symlink, the changes appeared immediately without having to restart Nginx.